# Problematic If-statement, unused variable error

Tags: objective-c, scope

i am new to programming and i need your help...
i have a label named "typeLabel" that has a default label text se to "NiMH". This text changes to NiCad through a pickerView. I want through an if-statement to change a multiplier value however "unused variable floatTime" halts  the program. The code is:

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    if ([typeLabel.text isEqualToString:@"NiCad"])
    {
        float floatTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.4;
    } else {
        float floatTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.5;
    }

    int intHourhs=(floatTime);
    float floatHours=(intHourhs);
    float floatMinutes=(floatTime-floatHours)*60;
    NSString *stringTotal = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%1.1i Hours and %.0f Minutes", intHourhs, floatMinutes];
    chargeLabel.text=stringTotal;
}
```

Comment: Note that the "unused variable" message is a warning, not an error. There should be a separate message about `floatTime` being *undeclared*, which is an error. Also, this is a language problem (Objective-C), not an IDE problem (XCode).

Comment: You can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. CocoaFu did it for you this time, but next time try it yourself. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: I declared the variable as proposed and that fixed the problem. However, there is another problem! Although the "typeLabel.text" changes values from "NiCad" to "NiMH", the result of "chargeLabel.text" remains the same, multiplied by the If-statement by 1.5

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. Read the FAQ section for more info on SO's format. If you have a new issue, you should ask a new question; just make sure you include a [complete, concise sample](http://sscce.org/). Comments are largely for clarifications. There's also the chat section (see link at top of page).

Comment: Thanks, i will have have it in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to move the declaration above the if statement:

```
float floatTime;
if ([typeLabel.text isEqualToString:@"NiMH"])
{
    floatTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.5;
} else {
    floatTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.4;
}
```

When you declare a local variable inside a scope it is not visible outside that scope.

Comment: I declared the variable as proposed and that fixed the problem. However, there is another problem! Although the "typeLabel.text" changes values from "NiCad" to "NiMH", the result of "chargeLabel.text" remains the same, multiplied by the If-statement by 1.5

Answer (score 1):

`float floatTime` is defined inside the if statements braces and they define it's scope.  Move it out:

```
float floatTime;
if ([typeLabel.text isEqualToString:@"NiMH"])
{
    floatTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.5;
} else {
    floatTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.4;
}
```

Curly braces define scope, things defined inside them are not available outside.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare float time in the main block of code, outside the if/else, that's why you are getting an error.  Try this:

```
-(IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
float floatTime;
  if ([typeLabel.text isEqualToString:@"NiMH"])
{
   floatTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.5;
} else {
   floatTime=([mAhLabel.text floatValue]/chargerSlider.value)*1.4;
}
```